# scroll able Checkboxes in windows 8 silver light Phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am creating a simple app with multiple checkboxes (say 55) on a single page where user gets to scroll down to tick whatever are his preferences. How do i implement it using XAML? Longlistselector? Multiselectitem? Virtualizing stack panel? or how? This is a windows 8.0 phone app (silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to use `StackPanel` inside `ScrollViewer`. So it would look like this:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="Checkbox 1" />
            <CheckBox Content="Checkbox 2" />
            <CheckBox Content="Checkbox 3" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

However, make sure that 55 check boxes won't affect performance of scrolling. If so, then you should split your layout to more pages or use `ListBox` with binding.